# Implement VSTS 2010 for Unit and Load Testing with accordance to TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have to implement VSTS 2010 for Unit and Load Testing.

But I didn't know the process of implementing VSTS 2010 but I know the process of performing load testing

I have to implement VSTS 2010 for Unit and Load on my present TFS environment.

Can anyone provide some advice and guidance with regard to implementing VSTS 2010 for unit and load along with TFS, so that any one can use VSTS like TFS.

Comment: Please try to be more clear. I have no idea what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio to create and run unit tests.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532.aspx

You can use TFS Team Build to automate running unit tests.
http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2009/06/03/tfs-team-build-2010-running-unit-tests.aspx

But running LOAD tests with TFS? hmmmm. I don't know if anyone has done it before but I don't like the idea. Load test environments need to be very controlled environments and I don't see a reason to do LOAD testing as a part of continuous integration.
I believe it can be done by digging into TFS 2010 Lab Management with virtual machines or something but it not worth the effort.